# Can I use a JR Hokkaido Round Trip Discount Ticket (Sapporo-Hakodate, return) with a stopover?

Tags: tickets, stopovers, japan-rail

Sapporo-Onumakoen (stop over) - Hakodate

and return trip:

Hakodate-Noboribetsu (over night) - Sapporo.

Total length of stay for this route is five days.

Comment: I do not know what a "JR Hokkaido Economy Ticket" is.

Comment: Possibly this? http://www2.jrhokkaido.co.jp/global/english/pticket/
Even then, I'm not sure I really understand the question... It would need reformulation for it to be clear.

Comment: Hi, I still don't understand what your question is all about. Could you elaborate? If you edit it sufficiently and make it clear, it might be reopened.

Comment: What is missing from your question most importantly is a direct reference (such as a link) to the tickets you are referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I see, JR Hokkaido is trying to advertise in English some of the (many) discount tickets that are usually advertised in Japanese only, but they don't give nearly as much information.

What you are looking at is probably [this](http://www.jrhokkaido.co.jp/CM/Otoku/005692/): 9,000 yen for a round-trip between Sapporo and Hakodate (or Shin-Hakodate-Hokuto). **No, those tickets do not allow stopovers of any length.** If you exit the ticket gates at a station, *any station*, your ticket for that leg will be retained and you cannot get it back.

If you want the ability to make [stopovers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66616/when-are-stopovers-permitted-on-japan-railways-jr-trains), you will need to buy regular base fare tickets, which cost 5,720 yen one-way.

Comment: @6t0936 If this is really what you were referring to, then please edit your question to clarify that so it can be reopened.

Comment: fkraiem, you are giving the answer i want!

Answer (score 2):

JR Hokkaido Ecomonic tickets are valid for one ride.  So if you stop for a night along the way (your return example), the ticket would likely not be valid the next day to continue to Sapporo.

But as with most travel rules, there are exceptions, which you need to ask of the ticketing agent when you buy your ticket(s).

http://www2.jrhokkaido.co.jp/global/english/pticket/about.html